# solve complex equations in MATLAB (Variable Equations)

Tags: matlab, math

I have some equations which include some parameters and variables.
Each variable defines and also exists in other equations. these are my equations:

```
syms Pof s Pon teta landa PIon PIof PISC
Pof = (s * y - teta + T * teta - landa + Pi * landa + alpha * p + Pon * b1 + w * b2)/(2 * b2);
s = -(y * (w - Pof))/q;
Pon = (q * s * y + 2 * w * y - 2 * w * y^2 + 2 * q * alpha + 2 * q * Pi * landa - q * teta + 3 * q * T * teta - q * landa + q * Pi * landa - q * alpha * p - 2 * y * Pof + 2 * y^2 * Pof + C * q * b1 + q * w * b2)/(2 * q * b1);
teta = (C - 3 * C * T - Pon + 3 * T * Pon)/2 * q;
landa = (-1/2) * (-1 + Pi) * (C - Pon);
Don = (1-p) * alpha - b1 * Pon + b2 * Pof - (1-y) * s + T * teta + landa * Pi;
Dof = p * alpha - b1 * Pof + b2 * Pon + y * s - (1-T) * teta - landa * (1-Pi);
PIon = (Pon-C) * Don - (1/2) * n * teta^2 - (1/2) * q * landa^2;
PIof = (Pof-w) * Dof - (1/2) * L * s^2;
PISC = PIon + PIof;
```

How I can solve these in order to get a numeric answer for each variable?
(I don't want parametric answers)

Comment: Solve in terms of what. What are the variables you want to solve for? You have 10 equations and 8 symbols.

Comment: @JohnAlexiou `syms Pof s Pon teta landa PIon PIof PISC` these are my variable.

Comment: You have more equations than variables ... and the expressions are a direct evaluation of `[Pof,s,Pon,teta,landa,Don,Dof,PIon,PIof,PISC]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equations as stated are

[image: fig1]

which can be arranged as a linear system **A** **x** = **b** as follows

[image: fig2]

which you solve in Matlab as **x** = **A** \ **b**

On further investigation, it seems **A** is singular since it's 10×8 in size and cannot be inverted. So a least-squares solution is needed where

**x** = inv(**A**<sup>T</sup>* **A**)* **A**<sup>T</sup> **b**

Comment: Hi again, I have some problem; I'll Edit my post.
If you have time, help me, please.
Thanks

Comment: @Alexander please remove the edit and post a new question.